# AdvancedDataGrid width Issue on Scaling

Tags: advanceddatagrid

I need an immediate help with Regards to Flex 4 scaling behavior.

Problem:
In our project we have the custom ADG (AdvancedDataGrid) and a zoomer control in bottom to control it's scaling, the scale value is directly binded to the scaleX & scaleY properties of ADG,
We recently migrated our flex 3 project to flex 4 sdk (compilation only, rest of the code are still using flex 3 MX components), In flex 3 everything used to work fine, The zoomer control used to increase and decrease the ADG magnification, but after the flex 4 migration, the magnification is happenning but the visible width of the ADG is also getting changed, that is causing the empty space to appear (in right) in case of zoom out and extra horizontal scroll bar incase of zoom in. This doesn't happen for Height. Height is always taking 100%.

I compared the UIComponent class in flex 3 vs flex 4 and found significant difference in set scaleX/scaleY methods, perhaps this change is causing this behavior change.

Please advise/help!

Thanks
Abhishek